# Liferay Social Office - Is there a Related Content portlet?

Tags: liferay, related-content

I'm looking for the Related Content portlet in Liferay, and in particular for Social Office. I know about the Asset Publisher and Related Assets portlet. But I can seem to find the Related Content portlet? I'm using 6.1 CE of Liferay and I just installed the newest Social Office CE yesterday. Was this portlet removed/deprecated?

This page claims that there is this feature: http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-social-office/features

And this page says the portlet should already be there. But I don't see it.
http://www.liferay.com/documentation/social-office/2.0/user-guide/-/ai/lp-2-0-soen01-social-office-features-0

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Related Assets will only display when there actually are related assets. Further, AFAIK it will not show when you show *all* blogposts (the documentation says it's on the Blogs page), but when you select one article.

Alternatively, if you have sufficient permissions, enable "Edit Controls" in the dockbar and the portlet will appear (greyed out and without content).

Another alternative, if it indeed is not there, you might be able to change the social office site template and add it to the template.

Comment: Thanks. I'm specifically looking for the "Related Content" portlet. Does this portlet even exist?

http://i42.tinypic.com/30wouhe.png